# Make packets according to dimension

Tags: php

I am trying to create packets according to information I have in database.

Database is organized this way:

```
ID ORDERID DIMENSION QUANTITY 
1    21    8400       25
2    21    7200       8
3    21    4300       5
4    21    3800       7
```

First thing , getting information from db

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, ORDERID, DIMENSION, QUANTITY FROM dimension WHERE ORDERID = 21 ORDER BY DIMENSION DESC";

$q = $conn => query($sql);

while($r = $q->tech()){
  $dim  =$r['DIMENSION '];
  $quant  =$r['QUANTITY '];
}
```

Then I retrieve data from another table, for ex. I get number 10.

```
$query = "SELECT QUANTITY FROM panel WHERE ID = 21; 

$q = $conn->query($query);

while ($r=$q->fetch()){
  $number = 10;
}
```

It is very important to make packing from the longest dimension.

For ex. I have dimension 8400 quantity 25. Max number of panel is 10, that means that I will have two packets that will have per 10 panels, remains 5.
5 goes to next dimension and we take maximum number of that panel to reach $number. Remaining of that dimension goes to next dimension and it keeps like that.

Once I get all information I need to make packing, at the end packing solution should be

```
-------------------
8400 x 10 - Packet1
-------------------
8400 x 10 - Packet2
-------------------
8400 x 5
7200 x 5 - Packet3
-------------------
7200 x 3
4300 x 5
3800 x 2 - Packet4
-------------------
3800 x 5 - Packet 5
-------------------
```

Once I get this data, I should insert it into database 
where 8400 would be dimension, 10, panels, "Packet1" - name

I am stuck, don't have an idea how to perform this. I don't know if algorithm exists for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
// assuming you have collected the results from your sql query like this:
while($r = $q->tech()) $dat[]=array($r['DIMENSION'],$r['QUANTITY']);

// you will end up with an array $dat: (dimension, quantity) like this:
// $dat=array(array(8400,25),array(7200,8),array(4300,5),array(3800,7));
// package size:
$n=10;

$cnt=0;                        // initialize package counter
$pack=array();                 // set up first package
$d=array_shift($dat);          // get first lot $d from $dat

do {     
  if ($d[1]>0){    
    $take=min($d[1],$n-$cnt);  // decide how much to take out ...
    $cnt+=$take;               // increase package counter
    $d[1]-=$take;$pack[]=array($d[0],$take); // tranfer the goods ...
                               // if package is full, start next one
    if ($cnt==$n) {$packs[]=$pack; $pack=array(); $cnt=0;}
  } else if(count($dat)>0){    // still elements in $dat left?
    $d=array_shift($dat);      // get the next lot $d from $dat
  } else break;    
} while(true);
if ($cnt>0) $packs[]=$pack;    // collect the last "stranded" package ...

echo str_replace("]],","]],\n ",json_encode($packs));    // as JSON string
// print_r($packs);            // conventional (bulky) PHP object notation
```

This leads to the following result (JSON notation):

```
[[[8400,10]],
 [[8400,10]],
 [[8400,5],[7200,5]],
 [[7200,3],[4300,5],[3800,2]],
 [[3800,5]]]
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Once I get that information, I need to store it in db. My table is organized ID | ORDERID | DIMENSION | QUANTITY | NAME. I have order id, dimesion ( 8400 ) and quantity 10. order name could be Packet1 for first set, for second set  Packet2, for third case  Packet3 for both sets would be same name 8400 and 7200. It increments by 1. Idk if that is possible. Thank you